# How to parse this format with NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to parse the following string to date format with **`NSDateFormatter`**

> Mon, 05 Aug 2013 00:00:00 +0000

What should I write as date format?

I've tried this but it did not work.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"Day, dd Mon yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

Comment: -1 For asking the same tired old question again and for even introducing things such as "Day" and "Mon" which exist *nowhere* in the standard (which, by the way, is [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) )

Comment: **Mon, 05 Aug 2013 00:00:00 +0000** this string or date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[df setDateFormat:@"eee, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss ZZZ"];
```

If this doesn't work, use this as a reference:

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Be sure to also pass the local for english, because if your device is not set to english you date formatter will fail.`[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"]];`

Comment: @rckoenes Better yet POSIX english (en_US_POSIX)

Comment: @borrrden You are right: In [Q&A1480](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html) Apple explains why you should use `en_US_POSIX`. Because if the date formate will change the `en_US_POSIX` will not. So add: `[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];`